# Submit POST to Facebook with Graph API issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, post, facebook-graph-api

I'm a junior dev and new to Facebook for Developers, I'm struggling a bit with the Graph API.  I went back and forth with the Docs, and I used the code it provided, but it doesn't seem to be fulfilling the need.

I'm making a React app, and part of it is I'd like to be able to submit a post, AKA a POST request, to the Users own Facebook Page with the text box I've made (using DevExtreme's HTML editor) I went through all the reading to target the specific users page as opposed to a Page...Page, and I'm 99% sure my syntax is ok but something is clearly off.

The goal is on the 'click' of the submit button, submit the value of the text inside the text box.  You'll see in the FB.api section I have a console.log, and it is returning the 'response' - but it's just the Users name/profile ID, not any info associated with the post like the time created or the post ID.  Based on that, I think I'm connected to some part of Facebook's API but it's just not the part I want! Am I doing something backwards here?

```js
/*global FB*/
import React from 'react';
import HtmlEditor, { Toolbar, MediaResizing, Item } from 'devextreme-react/html-editor';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import $ from 'jquery'

const headerValues = [false, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var message = $('.ql-editor .ql-blank .dx-htmleditor-content').text();
const created_time = new Date()
created_time.toUTCString();

function postSubmit() {
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        'POST',
        { "fields":"id,name,posts", "message": message },
        function(response) {
            response.posts.data.push(message, created_time)
        }
      );
}

class Poster extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isMultiline: true,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="widget-container">
        <HtmlEditor
          height="500px"
          width="500px"
          defaultValue={message}
        >
          <MediaResizing enabled={true} />
          <Toolbar>
            <Item name="undo" />
            <Item name="redo" />
            <Item name="separator" />
            <Item
              name="header"
              acceptedValues={headerValues}
            />
            <Item name="separator" />
            <Item name="bold" />
            <Item name="italic" />
            <Item name="strike" />
            <Item name="underline" />
            <Item name="separator" />
            <Item name="alignLeft" />
            <Item name="alignCenter" />
            <Item name="alignRight" />
            <Item name="alignJustify" />
            <Item name="separator" />
            <Item
              widget="dxButton"
              options={this.toolbarButtonOptions}
            />
          </Toolbar>
        </HtmlEditor>
        <Button onClick={postSubmit}>Click To Submit</Button>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}

export default Poster;
```

Comment: 1. You would need to post to the `feed` edge of the object, not the object itself. 2. You can not create posts on user profiles via API any more, that has been removed quite a while ago. (If you want the users of your app to be able to share something, then you can use the Share dialog for that.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you! When you say "not the object itself", you mean to post to ```/feed``` instead of ```/me``` ?

Comment: No, `/me/feed`. But again, that will only work for pages, not for user profiles.

Comment: @CBroe Gotcha, thanks for the insight.  Do you happen to know of any workarounds in order to post from an outside app (my own haha), to a user on Facebook's profile?

Comment: There are no workarounds.